# MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///?

Tags: python

```
for l in l1:
r = requests.get(l)
html = r.content
root = lxml.html.fromstring(html)   
urls = root.xpath('//div[@class="media-body"]//@href')
l2.extend(urls)
```

while running the above code this error coming. any solution??

MissingSchemaTraceback (most recent call last)

MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///?

Comment: What is the URL you're trying to access?  `requests.get()` is complaining that the URL does not start with `http:` or `https:`.

Comment: see my full code # edited

Comment: The error message would be clearer if it read "missing __protocol__" rather than "missing schema".  I looked at it for a long time and had to come here before noticing the http at the beginning of the URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
urls = root.xpath('//div[1]/header/div[3]/nav/ul/li/a/@href')
```

These HREFs aren't full URLs; they're essentially just pathnames (i.e. `/foo/bar/thing.html`).

When you click on one of these links in a browser, the browser is smart enough to prepend the current page's scheme and hostname (i.e. `https://host.something.com`) to these paths, making a full URL.

But your code isn't doing that; you're trying to use the raw HREF value.

Later on in your program you use `urljoin()` which solves this issue, but you aren't doing that in the `for l in l1:` loop.  *Why not?*

Comment: actually 
urls = root.xpath('//div[1]/header/div[3]/nav/ul/li/a/@href') is to scrap main content link like sports,business,world

and urls = root.xpath('//div[@class="media-body"]//@href') is for scrapping news content link 

and then at last i am joining it to make a complete link. because newspaper link changing everyday... 
i have done with other news website and its working fine but for this website ..the above error coming...what to do??

Comment: _and then at last i am joining it to make a complete link_ In the first `for` loop where you call `requests.get(l)`, you are NOT doing this.  Was my answer unclear?

Comment: now understood and its working now...... one more help....i want title and article should be opened in gui. how to do that??

Comment: What do you mean by _i want title and article should be opened in gui_?  Do you mean you want to start up a browser and open a specific link?

Comment: i have extracted news article(text format) from dnaindia.com and i want to show that article in python gui or in web browser( it should not open the link, the text which i extracted only that needed)  because link contains so many ad.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by _python gui_.  Perhaps a separate question would be better.

Comment: GUI Application with Tkinter

Comment: I don't know anything about Tkinter.  I think you should put that in a new question.